# Is SparkViewEngine dying?

Tags: template-engine, spark-view-engine

I am building a email service based on templates. I thought of using the spark view engine but it seems that It doesn't get much updates anymore.
Support on .NET4.0 is not even yet complete and it fails at runtime when used in a console app.
The little Intellisense support that was there in VS2008 doesn't seem to work on VS2010 (from the information I have found)

Should I avoid it?
What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Louis Dejardin, the author is speaking about the view engine at [NDC2010](http://www.ndc2010.no/agenda.aspx?cat=1071&id=-1&day=3728), in Norway. I guess it's far from being a dying project then :) good.

Answer (score 2):

There has also been talk, from Phil Haack and Louis Dejardin (both on the ASP.NET team) about getting some form of support "in the box" for Spark. That "support" may just be intellisense.

Comment: That would be amazing. I will ask Louis Dejardin in 2 weeks then :). thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do email based on templates, DotLiquid (http://dotliquidmarkup.org) could be a nice solution, expecially if you need your end users to edit templates without tampering your system.